# How to use AFNetworking 2 with Digest Authentication

Tags: objective-c, ios7, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, digest-authentication

I've been searching for "AFNetworking 2 with Digest Authentication" for a while and haven't found useful discussions about it (except [this one](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/551), but unfortunately it looks like it's for AFNetworking 1).

Here's my code without authentication:

```
NSString* apiURL = @"https://api.example.com/WS.asmx";
AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager
    GET:apiURL 
    parameters: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"ID", 1234 , nil]
    success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    }
    failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"WS request failed: %@", error);
    }
];
```

Where and how can Digest Auth code kick in?

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, but I had to do just this and I couldn't find any built in way to handle it.
The solution I used was to edit AFNetworkings AFURLSessionManager.m.
Basically you modify this delegate method to support http digest, heres a full example.

```
    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
                  task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
    didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
     completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
    {
        NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
        __block NSURLCredential *credential = nil;

        if (self.taskDidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge) {
            disposition = self.taskDidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(session, task, challenge, &credential);
        } else {
            if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
                if ([self.securityPolicy evaluateServerTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust forDomain:challenge.protectionSpace.host]) {
                    disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential;
                    credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
                } else {
                    disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge;
                }
            } else if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPDigest]) {
                NSDictionary *userkeys = [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] credentialsForProtectionSpace:challenge.protectionSpace];

                credential = [userkeys objectForKey:(NSString *)[[userkeys allKeys] objectAtIndex: 0]];
                if (credential) {
                    disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential;
                } else {
                    disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
                }
            }else {
                disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
            }
        }

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(disposition, credential);
        }
    }
```

You will need to add a credential to the sharedCredentialStorage before this challenge.
You can check the apple docs for that as it is fairly straight forward but make sure the protection space matches up exactly, including the realm.
I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I recently upgrade to AFNetworking-3, there's no `NSURLConnection` support anymore.

When I change to `NSURLSession`, I got same problem.

Thank you bob, edit AFNetworkings `AFURLSessionManager.m` works fine for me.

But after that, I found a easier way if `self.taskDidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` is set, we don't have to change AFNetworkings code.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

NSURLCredential *myCredential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:@"username" password:@"password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

[manager setTaskDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull task, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge * _Nonnull challenge, NSURLCredential *__autoreleasing  _Nullable * _Nullable credential) {
    if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0) {
        *credential = myCredential;
        return NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential;
    } else {
        return NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me awhile to figure this out and I didn't see any solutions for AFNetworking 4.0 (4.0 is needed as it removes the deprecated UIWebView which Apple now rejects if found), do this;

```
NSURLCredential *myCredential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:username password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

[manager setAuthenticationChallengeHandler:^id _Nonnull(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull task, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge * _Nonnull challenge, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable credential)) {
    if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0) {
        return myCredential;
    } else {
        return @(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

I just used the following code and worked fine

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:@"Username" password:@"Password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
[manager setCredential:credential];
```