# Digest access authentication for AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I am need use Digest authentication,but with AFNetworking it does not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what worked for me

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:@"Username" password:@"Password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
[manager setCredential:credential];
```

Comment: this is not working anymore on AFNetworking 3

Comment: which version.. it works for?

Answer (score 4):

To work with AFNetworking 3.0, the following code could be used for AFURLSessionManager.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];     
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

[manager setTaskDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull task, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge * _Nonnull challenge, NSURLCredential *__autoreleasing  _Nullable * _Nullable credential) {
    NSString *authenicationMethod = challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod;
    NSLog(@"Receive challenge: %@", authenicationMethod);
    if ([authenicationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPDigest]) {
        *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username" password:@"password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        return NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential;
    }
    return NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge;
}];
```

Comment: See my answer for AFNetworking 4.0; https://stackoverflow.com/a/63669120/821666